# TFS build giving error - The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio, build, tfs, sonarqube

We are using Visual Studio 2019 and TFS server 2015.
TFS build is giving below error:
Error: The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. The test execution process crashed while running the tests. To investigate further, open file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/CrashDumps/TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe.11108.dmp file in Visual Studio and choose "Debug in mixed mode".

##[error]VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1
##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeVSTestCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

- If we uncheck Code coverage enable checkbox, then build gets successful, its failing when we enable that check box.

Observation: Recently on server, Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 (17.2.5) got updated. After that TFS builds not working.

Please someone help to solve this issue.

Comment: Can anybody help with this issue please